# remove a block HTML with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, owl-carousel

I use owl-carousel in a project angularjs I try to reinit owl-carousel after data-change with `$(element).data('owlCarousel').destroy();` and remove this block:

```
<div class="owl-wrapper">
<div class="owl-item" ></div>
<div class="owl-item" ></div>
<div class="owl-item" ></div>
<div class="owl-item" ></div>
<div class="owl-item" ></div>
</div>
```

I try this:

```
 if(typeof $(element).data('owlCarousel') != 'undefined'){
                        $(element).data('owlCarousel').destroy();
                        $(element).find(".owl-item").removeClass("owl-item");                   
                    }
```

ON page load It's working fine but on data change it's not working for exemple I have 5 items to display then I shoud get 5 block `<div class="owl-item" ></div>` but I get my 5 items expected and more empty block .

Comment: *" it's not working"* is not a proper or actionable problem statement. Also please provide a [mcve]

Comment: sorry, I edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the whole element like this:

```js
const remove = el => el.parentElement.removeChild(el);

const owl = document.querySelector('div.owl-wrapper');

// remove it

remove(owl)

// check if it's removed (true = no such element in DOM) 

console.log(document.querySelector('div.owl-wrapper') === null)
```

```html
<div class="owl-wrapper">
<div class="owl-item" >1</div>
<div class="owl-item" >2</div>
<div class="owl-item" >3</div>
<div class="owl-item" >4</div>
<div class="owl-item" >5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @wostex it work almost with your help I get only one empty block in last position.

Comment: Do you want to remove it completely? @MedKostali

Comment: yes the empty block is <div class="owl-item" style="width: 294px;"><div class="owl-wrapper-outer"></div></div>  tank you.

Comment: @MedKostali I've edited my answer, now you completely remove this block. In `querySelector` specify the wrapper div, the one you want to erase from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using

```
$(".owl-item").removeClass("owl-item");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery **.remove()** method:

`$('div.owl-wrapper').remove();`

See https://api.jquery.com/remove/

The example based on the @Egor's solution:

```js
$('div.owl-wrapper').remove();

// check if it's removed (true = no such element in DOM) 

console.log(document.querySelector('div.owl-wrapper') === null)
```

```html
<div class="owl-wrapper">
<div class="owl-item" >1</div>
<div class="owl-item" >2</div>
<div class="owl-item" >3</div>
<div class="owl-item" >4</div>
<div class="owl-item" >5</div>
</div>
```